# Smalltalk own new method

Tags: smalltalk, gnu-smalltalk

```
Object subclass: Node [     

    |value|

    new [
        Transcript show: 'Test'.
            value := 6.
    ]

    getValue [
        ^value.
    ]

    set:sth [
        value := sth.
    ]

]

|data|
data := Node new.
Transcript show: (data getValue) printString ; cr. "nil"
data set:5.
Transcript show: (data getValue) printString. "5"
```

The problem is that a `new` method is never called, so I can not set values or call initialize function. Moreover after something like that:

```
object := Node new. "Not called"
object new. "Here is called"
```

the method is called. How to fix that?

Comment: Is that GNU Smalltalk?

Comment: Hmm... I guess so, does it change anything? In fact I have just started and compiling it under ideone so far.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`#new` must be defined on `Node class` to work:

```
Object subclass: Node [     

    |value|

    getValue [
        ^value.
    ]

    set: sth [
        value := sth.
    ]

]

Node class extend: [
    new [ | node |
        Transcript show: 'Test'.
        node := (super new).
        node set: 6.
        ^ node
    ]
]
```

Note that `value` cannot be accessed from `#new` in this case, so the setter must be called

Answer (score 3):

As far as I understand you defined new as a method of the instance and not a class.

When you call `Node new`, a message is sent to a class object `Node` and it creates an instance of itself that you assign to the `object` variable. Then when you send `new` to that variable, a receiver is an instance of `Node` and has your-defined `new`

Here is an example on how to add a method to the class in GNU Smalltalk http://www.gnu.org/software/smalltalk/manual/html_node/Defining-methods.html

Comment: @Fuv What smalltalk are you using? Maybe you should define a method as `class>>new [...`

Comment: I have checked and it is GNU Smalltalk gst 3.1
About your proposition I get: `prog.st:5: key class not found`

Comment: @Fuv added url to documentation in the answer